# Simple cross table with PHP and MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, populate

I have table:

```
date name hours
--------------
11    peter   12:00
11    peter   11:00
11    john    10:00
12    peter   9:00
12    john   13:00
13    peter   10:00
13    john    16:00

etc...
```

I just need to make MySQL query and PHP cross table (not sure is this the correct term) so it looks something like this:

```
        11   |  12   | 13 
-----------------------------------------
john  | 10:00 | 13:00 | 16:00
-----------------------------------------
peter | 12:00 | 9:00  | 10:00
        11:00 |
```

So far I got to the :

```
SELECT date, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS('|', name, hours) ORDER BY name) schedule 
FROM days
GROUP BY date
```

But I thing I got stuck on populating and making the table like the one above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT Name
   ,GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN Date = 11 THEN hours ELSE NULL END) AS `11`
   ,GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN Date = 12 THEN hours ELSE NULL END) AS `12`
   ,GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN Date = 13 THEN hours ELSE NULL END) AS `13`
  FROM days
 GROUP BY Name
```

You can also use this dynamic query for the same:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN `Date` = ''',
      `Date`,
      ''' THEN hours ELSE NULL END) AS `',
      `Date`, '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM Days;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT Name, ', @sql,'
                     FROM Days
                    GROUP BY Name
                  ');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Output:

```
|  NAME |          11 |    12 |    13 |
---------------------------------------
|  john |       10:00 | 13:00 | 16:00 |
| peter | 12:00,11:00 |  9:00 | 10:00 |
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/37156/8)

Comment: OH, that seems to make visual result I was looking for but the 11 part in the (Date = 11) its not variable,no?

Comment: @Iznogud - Sorry I didn't get you. What do you mean by *its not vasriable*?

Comment: Apart the mispeling :) I meant, that it should get the all the avaible dates in 'date' column and display them.

Comment: @Iznogud - Yeah then try that dynamic query. See the SQLFiddle linked at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: I see what you did and thats exactly what I need. It turn out its quite advance query after all. Obviously you are talking with a newbee here. How would you would populate the html/php table with this data?

Comment: @Iznogud - that should be a different question. But before you ask please search it.

Comment: Ok, thank you for time Ill will check it out and  thanks  again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you do something like:

```
 SELECT date, name, hours FROM days ORDER BY date
```

and then to display them you only need to do compare the date value, if it's different from the earlier make a new column.

Comment: Sure, how would you present in html/php table?